# I can't read the JSON file and get data from it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a keystore of values ​​in JSON. Everything should work through the arguments entered into the console. That is, the data is first written to a file, and then must be read from there.

Input: `python storage.py --key key_name --value value_name`

Output: `python storage.py --key key_name`

A function with arguments and a function with data entry work. But I had a problem with the file read function. I need to print the key by its value, or values ​​if there are several.

The recorded JSON looks something like this:

```
{"key": "Pepe", "value": "Pepeyaya"}{"key": "PepeHug", "value": "KekeHug"}{"key": "Pepega", "value": "Kekega"}{"key": "Pepe", "value": "Keke"}
```

I tried reading the file like this:

```
data = json.loads(f.read())
```

But the error is exactly the same

In other similar topics I saw that the "dictionaries" in JSON are written to the list. I tried something like this:

```
data = json.loads([f.read()])
```

Result:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list
```

Also:

```
data = json.load([f])
```

Result:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I tried to change the recording function, but I can't write everything to a pre-created dictionary, everything is written to the right of it. Something like this:

```
[]{"key": "Pepe", "value": "Pepeyaya"}{"key": "PepeHug", "value": "KekeHug"}{"key": "Pepega", "value": "Kekega"}{"key": "Pepe", "value": "Keke"}
```

Code:

```
import os
import tempfile
import json
import sys


def create_json(path):
  with open(path, mode='a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump([], f)


def add(key, value, path):
  with open(path, mode='a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    entry = {'key': key, 'value': value}
    json.dump(entry, f)


def read(a_key, path):
  read_result = ""
  with open(path) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    print(data)
    my_list = data
  for i in my_list:
    for key, value in i.items():
      if key == a_key:
        read_result += value + ", "
        print(value)



def main():
  storage_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'storage.json')
  if sys.argv[1] == "--key":
    arg_key = sys.argv[2]
    if len(sys.argv) <= 3:
      read(arg_key, storage_path)
    elif sys.argv[3] == "--value":
      arg_value = sys.argv[4]
      add(arg_key, arg_value, storage_path)
    else:
      print("Введите верные аргументы")
  else:
    print("Введите верные аргументы")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In general, from the attached code, now this error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 39 (char 38)
```

I need on request:

```
python storage.py --key Pepe
```

Get Pepe and PepeYaya values

Comment: Look at your output file, it is **not** a valid JSON file. It contains multiple JSON objects, just next to each other. You need to write out a single array containing all of those objects if you want to be able to parse it, not just randomly add an empty array.

Comment: a stands for append thats why its doing this. You simply put 2 json object next to each other which is invalid json as you can have only 1 parent. You can instead read the whole json content to a list, append the dicts  in native python and write to file again.

Comment: Or at least have a line break to get "JSON Lines".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this it's a basic storage method, this method is very bad for large json files but it's an example that show how can you do the job.

```
import os
import sys
import json

# storage.py key_name value

key =sys.argv[1]
value = sys.argv[2]
data_path = "data.json"

if os.path.isfile(data_path):
    with open("data.json") as target:
        json_data = json.load(target)
else:
    json_data = {}

json_data[key] = value

with open("data.json", "w") as target:
    json.dump(json_data, target)
```

in your case the problem is because the append flag when you open the file. If you need to write a new object you need to delete the last '}' of the json and add a ",object" item after that add the '}' char again.